# (anonymous function) Error with D3.Js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When using D3.Js and following this exact tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2S1AbEWX85o I'm getting the error (anonymous function) in the console. In line 20 there is: canvas.selectALL

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<script>

    d3.json("document.json", function (data) {

        var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500)

        canvas.selectALL("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", function (d) { return d.age * 10; })
                .attr("height", 50)
                .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 50; })
                .attr("fill", "blue")       
    })
</script>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the code you're getting the error with.

Comment: It should be `selectAll` (lowercase l). It's useful to also read the official API documentation when following third party tutorials. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_selectAll